# Python code to produce diagonal matrix with 1 above the main diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to write a python function that produce a zero matrix of size n by n that has 1 for all the elements above the main diagonal.

Here is my code:

```
def funtest(n):
    for i in range(0,n-2):
        s = (n,n)
        Y = zeros(s)
        Z = Y
        Z[i,i+1]=1          
return Z
```

But the result only give 1 in the (n-1, n-2) element of the matrix.

I am stuck and I really think my code is correct and have no clue where is the mistake. And how can I fix it? Can anybody please help?

Thanks.

Comment: You are resetting the matrix to zero on each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 10):

The `numpy.diag` function can do exactly this:

```
import numpy as np
print( np.diag(np.ones(4), 1) )
```

With the second argument (the `1`) the offset for the diagonal. It gives:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: So small compensation ;)

Answer (score 4):

Do you want ones on just a diagonal, or for the whole upper triangle?

There's a set of `np.tri*` functions to index and create upper and lower triangle arrays:

```
In [395]: np.triu(np.ones((5,5),int),1)
Out[395]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I could even create a diagonal with two `tri` calls

```
In [399]: np.tril(np.triu(np.ones((5,5),int),1),1)
Out[399]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Not that I'd recommend this over the `np.diag` function. :)

or

```
In [404]: np.diagflat(np.ones(4,int),1)
Out[404]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting your matrix to zero on each iteration. Move the `zeros` call outside the loop, and it works fine:

```
def funtest(n):
    s = (n,n)
    Y = zeros(s)
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        Y[i,i+1]=1          
    return Y
```

Note that you also need to loop to n-1, not n-2 (moving up a row only reduces the number of 1s by 1!). Here is the output of the fixed function above:

```
funtest(5)

array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This matches your method, but also see [the answer from Swier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247680/754456) using `numpy` builtin `np.diag(np.ones(n-1),1)`.

Comment: Thanks @mfitzp. But there is one thing that I don't understand about limit of the loop. Is true that A[1,3] gives the element in the (2,4) position of matrix A? So 1 row before the nth row should be (n-2)th row?

Comment: That's true, but the range loop is simply iterating the number of 1s you need. The offset is already determined by the Y[i, i+1]. Moving 'up' (or 'across') one element reduces the number of ones by 1. The range(0,5) will generate 0,1,2,3,4 (no 5), so for n=5 range(0,n-1) gives 0,1,2,3